# Advantages of non-partitioned table on hive?

Tags: hive

Are there any advantages of non-partitioned table on Hive -- their special use cases comparing to partitioned table?

It will be great if anyone could help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's put it that way: in the database world, partitioning can be used to solve different kinds of problems. As long as you have no explicit problem, don't bother with partitions *(i.e. "if it ain't broken, don't fix it")*. Whenever you hit a problem, ask a DB architect to find a solution - may involve partitioning, maybe not.

But Hive is not a typical database. Partitions are everywhere, just because it's a crude workaround for the lack of indexes...

*(Well, actually the ORC format has its own workaround [stores min/max values per column per stripe, which allows skipping useless stripes] so partitioning is less critical with that format)*

Comment: is there any drawback if no partition is used? I mean if there is a good practice Hive table must have partitions?

Comment: Again: there is no such thing as a *universal* good practice. That's why older guys with lots of field experience in older technologies are sometimes useful in the Hadoop world :-)

Comment: both partitioned and non-partitioned tables in Hive are good from design perspective? I am worry if using non-partitioned is not following good practices. :)

Comment: Judge for **each** table based on Volume and Velocity (would have been called Information Life Cycle a few years back) ==> how much data do you add every day? incrementally, or truncate-and-replace? do you typically query only recent data? etc.

Comment: I only need most recent data in the query, any advice is appreciated, :)